# JTable Change Input data

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using jquery-jtable plugin to display table. One of its field Notificaiton is getting JSON data then user can select e.g. group, pujan (users) to it. But when I save, JSON's id data is saved instead of name.

My question is how to save "name" instead of id?

```
    $('#TaskTableContainer').jtable({
        ....
        actions : {
            listAction : 'TaskController?action=list',
            createAction : 'TaskController?action=create',
            updateAction : 'TaskController?action=update',
            deleteAction : 'TaskController?action=delete'
        },
        ...
        notifyusers : {
            title : 'Notification',
            width : '10%',
            list: true,
            edit : false,
            create: true,
        },
        ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, I have achieved this through changing the JSON data.
By default id value is saved into database.

**Before**

```
[{"name":"user1", "id":0},{"name":"user2", "id":1}...]
```

**After**

```
[{"name":"user1", "id":"user1"},{"name":"user2", "id":"user2"}...]
```